# Jquery mask with white-spaces

Tags: html, jquery-mask

I use jquery mask plugin.

I wanted to mask id field, and for user-comfortable, I wanted the mask to put one white space between each 3 digits.

I wrote:

```
 $('#id').mask('999 900 000');
```

My problem is, that if user press:
 123456789

The value becomes:

789 456 123

instead:

123 456 789

**I found that the problem is only when dir='rtl'**

Comment: have you tried just using `.mask('999 999 999')`? the fact you go in descending order for values may be why the string is re-ordered.

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/oqfhuLzn/1/

Comment: LcSalazar - I found that the problem is only when dir='rtl'